# Firebase Auth signs out everytime app relaunches - SwiftUI & Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, visionos

My app keeps signing out every time I relaunch.

It used to run fine but since updating to Firebase 10.20.0 from >8.0.0 for VisionOS I am running into this issue.

**appnameApp**

```
@StateObject private var store = Store()

init() {
    // Initialise Firebase
    FirebaseApp.configure()

}

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(store)
        }
    }
 }
```

**ContentView**

```
@EnvironmentObject var store: Store

switch store.userAuthState {
case .signedIn:
    AppTabView()
        .environmentObject(store)
    
case .signedOut:
    LoginView()
    
case .undefined:
    LoadingView()
    
}

enum UserAuthenticationState {
    case undefined, signedOut, signedIn
}
```

**Store Object**

```
class Store : ObservableObject {

private var db = Firestore.firestore()

// Session Properties
@Published var userAuthState: UserAuthenticationState = .signedOut

@Published var session: User?
@Published var isEmailVerified = false
@Published var userEmail: String?

init () {
    handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [self] (auth, user) in
        if let user = user {
            print("StateDidChangeListener")
            self.userEmail = user.email
            self.session = user
            
            if let u = auth.currentUser {
                self.isEmailVerified = u.isEmailVerified
            }
            
            if self.profile == nil {
                self.fetchProfile(uid: user.uid)
            }
            
        } else {
            self.session = nil
            self.userAuthState = .signedOut
        }
    }
}

deinit {
    if let handle = handle {
        Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
    }
}
}
```

**Target:** VisionOS

**SPM Version:** 10.20.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
if let user = user {
    self.userAuthState = .signedIn //<< this
```

You just have to update the state

Comment: That's actually insane that I missed that it got removed! When I add the line back it gets stuck on LoadingView, because of case .undefined: state. Do you know why?

Comment: @RileyDev nothing here is ever setting “undefined” so no I can’t tell you why. Do you mind clicking on the green checkmark? And maybe upvoting?